# After upgrading to 12.04 LTS it returns incorrect password

Tags: login, password

After upgrading my netbook to the current version of 12.04, I am unable to login. When I try it returns

> incorrect password

even though it is the correct password.

I have tried to reset the password but it has made no difference. I really hope you can help as I have some personal files on the hard drive that I wish to save.

Comment: How have you tried to reset your password? Did you use a keyboard-layout resistant password? (what country is your keyboard from?)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the keyboard layout changed? Try the following:

- write your password in the login field so that you can see what you are typing
- when correct, copy and paste it into the password field
- enter your username in the login field
- submit and see what happens

You could also try to login on the console by pressing Ctrl-Alt-F1.

Comment: if it's a keyboard problem, won't the console share it?

Comment: @tucuxi At least I would give it a try, because maybe just the desktop environment is setting a strange locale.

Comment: Thanks Sebi..I will try that out tomorrow and give feedback if it works or not.
Strange how that thought never even occurred to me. So blur! ;-) I have already tried to change the root password in recovery mode but it did not seem to work. Will try Sebi's suggestion and then follow it with yours. Thanks again for the prompt response!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the root password from [recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode), using

```
passwd username
```

Where the username is your user-name. See also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86332/how-can-i-find-my-password?rq=1).